# How to add new custom field in default add user form through plugin

Tags: users

I am new in wordpress , started plugin development in wordpress a week ago . I have to add the new custom field in default *add user form* , is it possible . Then i if write wp_get_current_user() , is it possible to get the data which is added in the new custom field ? 
Any body please help . 
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. For that we will use 4 hooks (actions): show_user_profile, edit_user_profile, personal_options_update, edit_user_profile_update.

Here is the example how to add extra field to user in WordPress.

Adding user info fields function

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields', 10, 1 );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="user_img_path_image"><?php _e("Image path"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="user_img_path_image" id="user_img_path_image" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'user_img_path_image', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Path to country image."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="user_country_field"><?php _e("Country field"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="user_country_field" id="user_country_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'user_country_field', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e(""); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
<?php }
```

Here is the extra code for save and edit function

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_img_path_image', $_POST['user_img_path_image'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_country_field', $_POST['user_country_field'] );

}
// end - Add user info fields
```

Just copy and paste this code in your plugin or function.php and you must see new 2 fields in Wordpress backend user editing/adding page.

For extracting your date in frontend use this code:

```
$user_facebook_id_acc = get_the_author_meta( 'user_facebook_id_acc', $current_user_data->ID );
```

Comment: Hi! I have tried your code , it is working fine in edit user page , but the requirement was that to add the new field in the add new user page in backend , can you please tell its hook ?

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible. In WordPress, there is a concept of [Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/) and [Actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/), collectively known as "hooks". Hooks allow you to "hook into" WordPress to change values (filters) or to execute your own functions (actions).

For the WordPress user page, you should look into the following hooks:

- `show_user_profile` - Fires for the current user after the "About Yourself" section
- `edit_user_profile` - Fires when editing **another** user's profile after the "About the User" section

These two actions fire when viewing the page. Here, you can add your own code to display new fields, e.g.

```php
add_action( 'personal_options_update', function( $user ) {
    $my_field_value = $user->my_field_key; // 'my_field_key' is the user meta field key in wp_usermeta
    // You can also use
    $my_field_value = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'my_field_key', true );
?>
<input type="text" name="my_field_key" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $my_field_value ); ?>"/>
<?php
});
```

Then, you can use the following actions to update the user:
- `personal_options_update` - Fires when you update your own profile page.
- `edit_user_profile_update` - Fires when you update another user's profile.

```php
add_action( 'personal_options_update', function( $user_id ) {
    // You should escape and verify the input.
    $my_value = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'my_field_key', FITLER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( ! $my_value ) {
        delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_field_key' );
        return;
    }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_field_key', $my_value );
} );
```

This could use some better HTML to fit the page, and should be modified for your usage, but hopefully this gives you an idea of where to go. Take a look at `/wp-admin/user-edit.php` for more details.