# How can I add Author's phone number to wp profile and make it appear in wp-admin/edit.php columns

Tags: posts, author, user-registration

How can I add Author's phone number to wp profile and make it appear in wp-admin/edit.php columns? Someone pls help me out with code or plugins link. Thank you.

Comment: Look, for example, here: [custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/330367/how-to-add-new-custom-field-in-default-add-user-form-through-plugin), [custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246457/user-profile-custom-field), [table column](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27518/sortable-custom-columns-in-user-panel-users-php)

Answer (score 0):

The advanced custom fields plugin will probably do what you need. You can add field values to page templates using the plugins PHP functions